# Для каких задач используется Docker cовместно с Kubernetes и для каких задач используется только одна из этих технологий?

Tags: docker, devops, kubernetes

Предположим мы открываем вакансии разработчиков. И смотрим описание стэков проектов.
На одних проектах - есть **`Docker` + `Kubernetes`**. На проектах второго типа есть только **`Docker`** без **`Kubernetes`**. На проектах третьего типа есть только **`Kubernetes`** без **`Docker`**. Бывают проекты четвёртого типа - на них не докера, не **`k8s`**.

**Вопрос:** при каких задачах архитектор примет решение использовать **`Docker + Kubernetes`**? При каких задачах архитектор примет решение использовать только **`Docker`** (без **`Kubernetes`** и без **`OpenShift`**)? При каких примерно задачах архитектор может принять решение использование только **`Kubernetes`** (без докера)? При каких примерно проектах не целесообразно использовать ни одну из этих двух технологий? (и близко похожие технологии тоже не нужны).
Подразумевается, что архитектор - толковый специалист, который формирует стэк с максимальной эффективностью, чтобы решить все задачи с наилучшим качеством и с наименьшими сроками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку более опытные люди не торопятся отвечать на вопрос, попробую сформулировать, как сам понимаю из своего небольшого опыта работы с этими технологиями.

Использование k8s почти всегда подразумевает и использование docker. Просто в вакансиях про него могут не писать, т.к. при упоминании k8s он просто подразумевается.

Только Docker целесобразно использовать, когда наши задачи подразумевают отдельные, относительно независимые куски логики. Которыми можно управлять отдельно, и не заботится о том, как деплой одних контейнеров будет взаимодействовать с другими контейнерами.

Kubernetes же хорошо подходит там, где у нас десятки или даже сотни контейнеров, которые зависят друг от друга, и деплой которых нужно сложным образом оркестрировать.

Совсем без этих технологий удобно обойтись там, где вообще не нужна виртуализация - например, когда у нас система с довольно стабильной структурой на собственных серверах, которую не нужно будет часто и гибко менять.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересное мнение.

Comment: Если у вас появится более глубокое (точное) понимание - довнесите пожалуйста информацию в ваш ответ.